# How to save Matrix<float> to XML file?

Tags: c#, xml, matrix, emgucv, surf

I'm trying to use the SURF feature detector of emguCV in C# in order to detect the key points of an image.
I'm using this code:

```
Image<Gray, Byte> myImage = new Image<Gray, byte>("test.png");
SURFDetector surf = new SURFDetector(500, false);
VectorOfKeyPoint myKeyPoints = surf.DetectKeyPointsRaw(myImage, null);
Matrix<float> myDescriptors = surf.ComputeDescriptorsRaw(myImage, null, myKeyPoints);
```

So I'm having the key points in that Matrix. What I want to do is to save/export these key points in an .xml file.
Can someone help me on how to do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: did the given answer worked?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with XxmlSerializer and StringBuilder

```
String filePath = "";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
(new XmlSerializer(typeof(Matrix<float>))).Serialize(new StringWriter(sb), modelDescriptors); 

System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filePath , sb.ToString());
```

Reference:

http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Working_with_Matrices